# How to rebuild bluez

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

How can I rebuild bluez? Is it possible? Lets just say I want to change something in avctp.c for example. I download the latest bluez release from their website and make the change I need to make. Now, how do I get the changes to be effective; i.e. what do I need to do to rebuild bluetoothd?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: just compile and install with sudo permission

Comment: yeah I`m working my way through it now. Makes you appreciate the visual studio compiler!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is just to remake the whole bluez package with the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After that, you can run the configured bluetoothd executable form the /src directory by using `./bluetoothd`, or replacing the bluetoothd in /usr/sbin with the bluetoothd executable in /src so that every time the `bluetoothd` command is passed, the new configured executable is called.

Hope this helps.